# Can I process an image row- (or column-)wise using Metal?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, gpgpu, metal

I'm trying to create an implementation of [seam carving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving) which will run on the GPU using Metal. The dynamic programming part of the algorithm requires the image to be processed row-by-row (or column-by-column), so it's not perfectly suited to GPU I know, but I figure with images potentially thousands of pixels wide/tall, it will still benefit from parallelisation.

My two ideas were either

1. write a shader that uses 2D textures, but ensure that Metal computes over the image in the correct order, finishing one row before starting the next
2. write a shader using 1D textures, then manually pass in each row of the image to compute; ideally creating a view into the 2D textures rather than having to copy the data into separate 1D textures

I am still new to Metal and Swift, so my naïve attempts at both of these did not work. For option 1, I tried to dispatch threads using a threadgroup of Nx1x1, but the resulting texture just comes back all zeros – besides I am not convinced this is even right in theory, even if I tell it to use a threadgroup of height one, I'm not sure I can guarantee it will start on the first row. For option 2, I simply couldn't find a nice way to create a 1D view into a 2D texture by row/column – the documentation seems to suggest that Metal does not like giving you access to the underlying data, but I wouldn't be surprised if there was a way to do this.

Thanks for any ideas!